# Яндекс карта заливается голубым цветом при выводе меток

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При выводе меток в кластеризованном виде происходит что-то, что окрашивает яндекс карту в сплошной голубой цвет. Весь JS для вывода прилагаю ниже:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 5,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl']
        });
        $.getJSON(document.URL + 'get_all_events', function(data) {
            var myGeoObjects = data.map(item => {
                return new ymaps.GeoObject({
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: item['coordinates']
                    },
                    properties: {
                        clusterCaption: item['name'],
                        balloonContentBody: [
                            '<address style="font-style: normal">',
                            '<h3>Данные</h3>',
                            '<b>Данные: </b>МО "Название МО"<br>',
                            '<b>Данные: </b>ФИО Главы МО<br>',
                            '</address>'
                        ].join('')
                    }
                }, {
                    preset: "islands#darkGreenDotIcon",
                });
            })

            var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
                preset: 'islands#invertedDarkGreenClusterIcons',
                clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
                clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 800,
                clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth: 160
            });
            clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
            map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
            map.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
        })
    }
```

Любые идеи из-за чего это может происходить. При выводе одиночной метки этого не происходит.
При этой заливке кластеризованная метка остаётся кликабельной и выводит все описание.
Также прилагаю скрин.

[image: Визуальный баг карты]

**Дополнение**: В процессе тестов выяснил, что это не заливка, а океан, то-есть точки отрисовываются на столько далеко в океане, что даже при сильном отдалении - суши не видно. Это ни чуть не менее странно, потому что координаты, которые брались для тестов - это координаты объектов в Москве.

Comment: Выглядит будто у вас один единственный кластер и из-за этого `map.setBounds` перебрасывает вас куда-то в океан. Уберите `setBounds`. И проверьте данные, `getBounds` лишён смысла, если у вас всего один объект (потому что bounds схлопнутся в точку).

Comment: Дело к сожалению не в этом - удаление setBounds не помогло. точки с любыми координатами почему-то отображаются под Африкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я пробрасывал значение координат из PHP в виде строки, а нужно было делать это в формате массива double, содержащего 2 значения соответственно. Как только я это сделал - все сразу заработало как должно.

Answer (score 0):

возможна путаница ширины долготы center: [55.76, 37.64], попробуйте местами поменять.
Везде пишут, что в версии 2.1 их поменяли местами.
Где-то в настройках надо установить порядок координат метки

Comment: не, не помогло. Почему-то все метки группируются под Африкой. К примеру метка с координатами [53.917745, 27.595051] - это Беларусь, БГУИР корпус 1, и карты находят такие координаты, но при выводе этой метки из базы данных на карту - она оказывается под Африкой в одном кластере с любыми другими метками (там адреса по Москве).